# Using regex to parse hashtags from a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex, hashtag

I want to extract out hashtags from a sentence. For eg-
if the sentence is

```
#test1.#test2 #test3 www.google.com/#test4 www.google.com/hello#test5
```

the hashtags would be

```
#test1
#test2 
#test3
```

but not #test4 or #test5 as they are part of URLs

I was trying to make the regex for this. till now i have

```
/(^|\s)#(\w+)\b/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/WPeSdE/1

this takes care of #test1 and #test3 but fails to get #test2.

Please help.

Comment: i guess you want [this](https://regex101.com/r/BpBtM2/1)

Comment: @PavneetSingh but it can be a fullstop before the word, or comma, or any symbol after which a word can come, even without a space after the symbol

Comment: #(\w+) work fine, no ?

Comment: Maybe [`(?:^|[^\/])\B#(\w+)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/xmq5BS/1)?

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant  
#(\w+) will match #test4 and #test5 also. but  i dont want those to match as they are part of a URL

Comment: @wiktorStribiżew OP said any symbol so won't work for this input `#test1/#test2 #test3 ` :(

Comment: Pretty hard to distinguish between #test5 being part of an url and #test2 being not. You either need a *really really* complex regex, or you write some more code to first tokenize the text into normal text and urls and then find the hashtags in the normal text, especially if you would need to extract/replace/highlight both the urls and the hashtags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed a very complex regex to support what i needed.
In the end, for now i ended up using hashtag function of twitter.txt library. handles all the cases i was stuck with.

Answer (score 1):

Match URLs and match *and capture* the hashtags, and just grab the Group 1 contents:

```
/\b(?:(?:https?|ftps?):\/\/|www\.)\S+|#(\w+)\b/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GCr07H/2).

**Details**:

- `\b(?:(?:https?|ftps?):\/\/|www\.)\S+` - a URL like pattern:

  - `\b` - word boundary
  - (?:(?:https?|ftps?)://|www.)` - either of:

    - `(?:https?|ftps?):\/\/` - `http://`, or `https://` (or same with `ftp/ftps`)
    - `www\.` - or `www.`
  - `\S+` - 1 or more chars other than whitespace
- `|` - or
- `#(\w+)\b` - a hash symbol, then Group 1 capturing one or more word chars (the hashtag) followed with a word boundary.

See the JS demo below:

```js
var rx = /\b(?:(?:https?|ftps?):\/\/|www\.)\S+|#(\w+)\b/gi;
var str = `#test1.#test2 #test3 www.google.com/#test4 www.google.com/hello#test5`;
var m, res =[];
while ((m = rx.exec(str)) !== null) {
   if (m[1]) res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```